# Is it possible maximize the window without JSNI

Tags: gwt, window, gxt, maximize

I'm using this function to maximize the window:

```
/**
* Resize the principal window
*/
public static native void resizeWindow() /*-{
      top.window.moveTo(0,0);
      top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
}-*/;
```

is it possible to maximize the browser window without JSNI ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the built in [Window.moveTo()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#moveTo%28int,%20int%29), and [Window.resizeTo()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#resizeTo%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: Hi, yes, I already checked this, my problem is how to get the avail width and height...

Comment: I couldn't find a built in solution to get screen.availWidth&Height. According to [this link](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t10), they are supported by all browsers GWT supports so it can't be a cross-browser related thing. I have also checked the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list) but couldn't find anything. I guess you can always create an issue to have this feature added.